# Change Visual Studio Developer Profile

Tags: ide, visual-studio-2013

Within Visual Studio there used to be, and I'm sure there still is an option to say what kind of developer you are. I would check 'a crap one' but that was not an option so instead I would go for something like "c# web".

The advantage of this is then every new project defaults to C# / Web.

Now in Visual Studio 2013 everything is defaulting to VB.Net and I want to set up VS to be as above "c# web". I cant remember what "it" - this IDE profile option -  was called.

I've been through Tools>Options but cant see for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto

```
TOOLS / Import and Export Settings...

Click "reset all settings"

It will ask if you want to backup your current settings.

finally, you can select the profile you are after.
```